# Is it possible to link one table to another with entity framework core without FKs?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables company and user. Company will have one created by user and one modified user - these will be admin users. User will belong to one company but one admin user could create or modify multiple companies.

I'm having a hard time using entity framework core in my .net core app to join company and user so when I get a company record I have the created by and modified user information.

My company and user classes look like this:

```
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public Guid Created_By { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public Guid Modified_By { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
        public string Company_Name { get; set; }
    }
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column("CREATED")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Column("CREATED_BY")]
    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Column("MODIFIED")]
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    [Column("MODIFIED_BY")]
    public Guid? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [Column("FIRST_NAME")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column("LAST_NAME")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Column("EMAIL")]
    public override string Email { get; set; }
    [Column("NORMALIZED_EMAIL")]
    public override string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    [Column("EMAIL_CONFIRMED")]
    public override bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    [Column("USER_NAME")]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    [Column("NORMALIZED_USER_NAME")]
    public override string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    [Column("COMPANY_ID")]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Column("PHONE_NUMBER")]
    public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Column("PHONE_NUMBER_CONFIRMED")]
    public override bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    [Column("TITLE")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Column("ACTIVE")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [Column("ROLE_ID")]
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    [Column("TYPE_ID")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    [Column("PASSWORD_HASH")]
    public override string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    [Column("SECURITY_STAMP")]
    public override string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    [Column("CONCURRENCY_STAMP")]
    public override string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    [Column("TWO_FACTOR_ENABLED")]
    public override bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    [Column("LOCKOUT_END")]
    public override DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    [Column("LOCKOUT_ENABLED")]
    public override bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    [Column("ACCESS_FAILED_COUNT")]
    public override int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext class looks like this:

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
    {
        public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("COMPANY").Property<Guid>("Created_By");
            builder.Entity<Company>().HasOne(x => x.CreatedByUser).WithOne().HasForeignKey("Created_By");
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("USER");
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("USER_CLAIMS");
            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("IDENTITY_ROLES");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId });
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("IDENTITY_USER_ROLES");
        }
    }
```

And I was trying to get companies like this:

```
public async Task<List<Company>> GetAllCompanies()
{
     return await _locationDbContext.Companies.ToListAsync();
}
```

Currently I am getting this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'You are configuring a relationship between 'Company' and 'ApplicationUser' but have specified a foreign key on 'Created_By'. The foreign key must be defined on a type that is part of the relationship.'

Is there an easier way to do this? Really all I want is the username of the user that created of modified the company record? If I was doing this with just sql I would just use a basic Join but Im not sure how to do that with entity framework. Worst case I would just get all the companies and then loop through doing a select on the user table where ID = Created_By

Comment: *"Is it possible to link one table to another with entity framework core without FKs?"* - No.

Comment: *one admin user could create or modify multiple companies* -- Makes me wonder why it's a 1:1 association.

Answer (score 0):

As @IvanStoev noticed without FKs it is not possible.  But you  can still use EF to join 2 tables.

In your case you have to unmap user from company and maybe it is a good idea to make user Guid nullable:

```
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Company_Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
       public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        public Guid Created_By { get; set; }
        public Guid Modified_By { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
         // or better
         [NotMapped]
         public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ApplicationUser ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
        //or better
         [NotMapped]
        public string ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
     
    }
```

and remove

```
builder.Entity<Company>().HasOne(x => x.CreatedByUser).WithOne().HasForeignKey("Created_By");
```

you still can join them like this

```
var companies= (
    from c in _locationDbContext.Companies
    join uc in _locationDbContext.ApplicatonUser on c.Created_By equals uc.Id
join um in _locationDbContext.ApplicatonUser on c.Modified_By equals um.Id
   
    select new Company
    {
        ....
      CreatedByUser = uc,
       ModifiedByUser = um
      // or usually
         CreatedByUser = uc.FirstName + " " + uc.LastName,
         ModifiedByUser = um.FirstName + " " + um.LastName,

    }).ToList();
```

Comment: so this gets rid of my errors but no user data is attached to the company record

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but, IMO, I don't see the point in adding complexity when the idea behind EF is to simplify things. For a simple many-to-one relation you don't need to create the query and joins manually or to configure it in `OnModelCreating()`, making it more tedious to maintain. I'll appreciate if you develop a bit more on the advantages of doing it this way.

Comment: @V.Lorz  You are welcome. I am really sorry, but it was you who was asking how to make it. You should think if you  really needed it before asking. I spent a lot of my  time just to show you one  of the ways. I use similar code for grid views  since I usually only need 5-6 columns for it.

Comment: @Sergey. Sorry, but I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of accomplishing this.

This is a simplified version of class `Company`:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    //
    // Relations
    public string CreatorID { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }

    public string LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

`CreatorID` and `LastModifiedByID` will be used by EF for determining the FK's. These are the fields you have to work with when updating the Db, not `Creator` and `LastModfiedBy`, yet you can also do it but with more lines of code.

Now, you can add companies the usual way, this code searches for the company, and creates one if not found, just sample code, not serious, really:

```
var companyName = "My company";
var company = context.Companies.Include(c => c.Creator).Include(c => c.Creator).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == companyName);

if (company == null)
{
    company = new Company
    {
        Name = "My company",
        CreatorID = user.Id,
        LastModifiedByID = user.Id
    };
    context.Companies.Add(company);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And retrieving the companies with all relations filled is a matter or using calls to `Include()` and `ThenInclude()`, like here:

```
var companies = context.Companies.Include(c => c.Creator).Include(c => c.Creator).ToList();
```

I omitted all filtering logic for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Sure they can do that. But how it satisfies *"without FKs"* criteria from the question?

Comment: It doen't. It stisfies _"Is there an easier way to do this? Really all I want is the username of the user that created of modified the company record?"_.